# vba for matching row data records for specific fields with the main column field that has data to be transfered to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, row

I have two sheets in Excel. Sheet2 has all the output data table from a data base source. I have been trying to code a VBA that can transfer specific data records from sheet2 to sheet1. I have tried to develop a criteria that can make data from a specific column in sheet2 to be transferred automatically to sheet1 in a specific cell if the row data for specific records of around 4 field columns, matches up with the main column record that has the data to be transferred.

For example I have series of data in sheet 2 as below

```
            LIMIT    SALES    REGION   LOCATION  ITEM
            422234   4768.24  HR       1         BUIL
            343222   190.73   BP       2         CON
            432220   1494.62  OP       1         EQ
            343332   1302.66  BP       1         AR
            433322   3881.67  BP       1         NO
```

The criteria is, sales record for item BUIL can only show on a specific cell in sheet1 if the row in sheet2 shows- Region "OP", location "2". Same rule will apply for the limit record to show in sheet1. Sheet1 has limit and sales as columns and items as rows.

Comment: I think this might benefit from some sample data to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are the rows in your data series on sheet 2 unique? For example, for `BUIL` there will only ever be one record with region `HR` and location `1`?

Comment: @Remnant thank you for your response. Yes the data series on sheet 2 are unique.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help you get started.

Suppose you have your database data (as shown) in `Sheet 2` starting in Range A1 and on `Sheet1` you have as follows:

```
    A        B        C
1   Item     Limit    Sales
2   BUIL
3   CON
4   EQ
    etc...
```

The following code will work down your list of items in `Sheet1` and if it finds a match in your data on `Sheet2` it will then check to see if the criteria are met i..e `Region` = "OP" and `Loaction` = 2:

```
Sub GetSalesAndLimit()
    Dim items As Range, entries As Range, item As Range, entry As Range, row As Long

    Set items = Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).row)
    Set entries = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").End(xlDown).row)

    For Each item In items
        For Each entry In entries
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                If entry = item Then
                    If entry.Offset(0, -2) = "OP" And entry.Offset(0, -1) = 2 Then 'Criteria is region = 'OP' and Loaction = 2
                        item.Offset(0, 1) = entry.Offset(0, -4) 'Limit
                        item.Offset(0, 2) = entry.Offset(0, -3) 'Sales
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next entry
    Next item
End Sub
```